# Centroid of Triangle problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I tried an approach using vectors to solve this problem, but I wasn't able to find the answer. Any help would be great, thanks for all of your help in advance!

Problem: Let $G$ denote the centroid of triangle $ABC$. If $ AG^2+BG^2+CG^2 = 41 $ then find $ AB^2+AC^2+BC^2 $.

Answer (score 2):

By [an identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Triangle_centroid) your desired sum is three times the given sum. So your answer is $3 \cdot 41 = 123$.

To prove the identity, I suppose you would use the fact that the distance from a vertex to the centroid is $2/3$ the length of the corresponding median. You can use analytic geometry to look at the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(p,0)$, and $(q,r)$. You can easily find the coordinates of the midpoints of the sides and of the centroid, so the lengths are easy to compare.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I wasn't aware of that identity, thanks for linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Stewart's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) gives that the squared length for a median is given by:
$$ m_a^2 = \frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4}$$
and $AG=\frac{2}{3}m_a$, so:
$$AG^2+BG^2+CG^2 = \frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{3}{4}(AB^2+AC^2+BC^2)$$
and the answer is $3\cdot 41=123$.